# Trying to use flask-mail: AttributeError: 'Mail' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, email, flask, flask-mail

I'm trying to send an email with flask-mail and I'm gettin this error.

My code is:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        msg = Message("Hey there", sender='mymail@gmail.com', recipients=['sometemporaryemail@emailhost99.com'])
        mail.send(msg)
        return render_template("index.html")
```

And these are my configurations:

```
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 465
app.config["TESTING"] = False
app.config["MAIL_USE_TLS"] = False
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = 'mymail@gmail.com'
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = 'my password'
app.config["MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER"] = 'mymail@gmail.com'
app.config["MAIL_MAX_EMAILS"] = None
app.config["MAIL_SUPRESS_SEND"] = False
app.config["MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENTS"] = False

mail = Mail(app)
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the Mail class. This class belongs to a external package?

Comment: @VictorAlessander I'm using flask-mail

Comment: Do you have anything different than mail instance `mail = Mail(app)` named as 'mail' too? Probably it is referencing to another instance that is also called as 'mail'.